# Complete border on page of print of Web page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am having a web page and on button of print. 
when i click on that button i am trying to print that web page

Here is my button

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ToolTip="Cancel" AlternateText="Print"
                ImageUrl="~/admin/images/print_btn.png" OnClientClick='javascript:window.print();' />
```

My web page contains more than 3 print page. I have set a border on Media Print. 
but it is not working properly.

there is only one bottom border that is at the last page.
I need borders on each page of print.

Is it possible using javascript or jquery? 
if it is possible using c# then also let me know

here is my code

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print
    {
        .TblBorder
        {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: solid 1px black;
        }
        .TblBorder td
        {
            border: solid 1px black;
        }
        .TblBorder th
        {
            border: solid 1px black;
        }

    }
</style>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="2">
<tr class="printable">
    <td colspan="3" align="center" style="color: Black; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold">
        <asp:Label ID="lblHeading" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="non-printable" visible="false" runat="server" id="trPrintPlantandMachinery">
    <td colspan="3" align="left">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnPlantMachinery" runat="server" CssClass="left_panel" Text="<b>1. Download & Print  Plant & Machinery List</b>"
            OnClick="lnkbtnPlantMachinery_Click" Font-Underline="true"></asp:LinkButton>
    </td>
</tr>      
<tr class="printable">
    <td style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: Black;"
        width="49%">
        Date of Visit the Enterprise
    </td>
    <td style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: Black;"
        width="1%">
        :
    </td>
    <td width="50%" style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">
        <asp:Label ID="txtDateofVisit" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="printable">
    <td style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: Black;"
        width="49%">
        Application Number
    </td>
    <td style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: Black;"
        width="1%">
        :
    </td>
    <td width="50%" style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblApplicationNo" runat="server" Text="-"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="printable">
    <td width="49%" style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;
        color: Black;">
        Scheme Name
    </td>
    <td width="1%" style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: Black;">
        :
    </td>
    <td width="50%" style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblSchemeName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="printable">
    <td width="49%" style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;
        color: Black;">
        Name of Enterprise
    </td>
    <td width="1%" style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: Black;">
        :
    </td>
    <td width="50%" style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblUnitName" runat="server" Text="-"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="printable">
    <td width="49%" style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;
        color: Black;">
        Enterprise Address
    </td>
    <td width="1%" style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: Black;">
        :
    </td>
    <td width="50%" style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblIndustryUnitAddress" runat="server" Text="-"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" border="0">
<tr>
    <td style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: Black;"
        width="49%">
        Constitution of The Unit
    </td>
    <td style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: Black;"
        width="1%">
        :
    </td>
    <td width="50%" style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblConstitutionUnit" runat="server" Text="-"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: Black"
        colspan="3">
        <u>Entrepreneur's Profile Details</u>
    </td>
</tr>


</table>
```

Comment: I wonder why .asp people never publish the HTML markup but the ASP one...

Comment: Probably best to also show your non asp encoded `@media print` CSS along with some non asp encoded HTML.